# Why isn't this random color method working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, random, uicolor

I have a for loop inside the drawRect method that draws a number of circles to fill the screen. I'm trying to make it so each circle has a new random stroke. For some reason nothing is showing up. Here is my randomColor method:

```
    -(UIColor *) randomColor
{
    int red, green, blue, alpha;

    red = arc4random_uniform(255);
    green = arc4random_uniform(255);
    blue = arc4random_uniform(255);
    alpha = arc4random_uniform(255);

    UIColor *colorToReturn = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:alpha];

    return colorToReturn;
}
```

and I try implementing it here:

```
-(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGRect bounds = [self bounds];

    // Firgure out the center of the bounds rectangle
    CGPoint center;
    center.x = bounds.origin.x + bounds.size.width / 2.0;
    center.y = bounds.origin.y + bounds.size.height / 2.0;

    // The radius of the circle should be nearly as big as the view
    float maxRadius = hypot(bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height) / 2.0;

    // The thickness of the line should be 10 points wide
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 10);

    // The color of the line should be gray (red/green/blue = 0.6, alpha = 1.0)
//    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 1.0);
    // The same as
//    [[UIColor colorWithRed:0.6 green:0.6 blue:0.6 alpha:1.0] setStroke];
    // The same as

//    [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];

    // Draw concentric circles from the outside in
    for (float currentRadius = maxRadius; currentRadius > 0; currentRadius -= 20) {
        // Add a path to the context
        CGContextAddArc(ctx, center.x, center.y, currentRadius, 0.0, M_PI * 2.0, YES);

        [[self randomColor] setStroke];

        // Perform drawing instructions; removes path
        CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

`UIColor` takes a float between 0 and 1 as a value for its RGB components:

```
 UIColor *colorToReturn = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:red/255.0 green:green/255.0 blue:blue/255.0 alpha:alpha];
```

Comment: Wow, that was easy. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I use the two macros below to get a random color. The first one is a straightforward macro that I often use while setting colors. The second one returns a random color using it:

```
#define _RGB(r,g,b,a) [UIColor colorWithRed:r/255.0 green:g/255.0 blue:b/255.0 alpha:a]
#define kCLR_RANDOM_COLOR _RGB(arc4random()%255, arc4random()%255, arc4random()%255, 1)
```